# Fast loading large data Azure SQL

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure-sql-database

There is a problem. I have every day to update and download large amounts of data. About 140 mb. These data are taken from the file. These very long loaded 9000 records are loaded for 10 minutes. Despite the fact that when I used a custom sql server data load faster.

Below is my code to load the data:

```
var InBase = FrmMain.allRecords.ToList(); 
var allcats = FrmMain.allCats;
int curCategory = 0;
            for (int jrCnt = rCnt; jrCnt <= arrayTable.GetUpperBound(0); jrCnt++)
            {
                while (operations.Count(x => x.IsAlive) >= 100) ;

                var prcI = new Price();

                if (arrayTable[jrCnt, nametov] != null)
                    prcI.name = arrayTable[jrCnt, nametov].ToString();

                if (productsInBase.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == prcI.name) != null) 
                {
                    var finded = productsInBase.FirstOrDefault(x => x.name == prcI.name && x.company==company);
                    prcI.ID = finded.ID;
                }

                if (arrayTable[jrCnt, pricetov] != null)
                {
                    decimal parsdec;
                    if (decimal.TryParse(arrayTable[jrCnt, pricetov].ToString(), out parsdec))
                        prcI.prc = parsdec;
                }

                prcI.category = curCategory;

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(prcI.name) && prcI.prc == 0)
                {
                    var cat =
                        allcats.FirstOrDefault(
                            x =>
                            x.findname != "NaN" &&
                            x.findname.ToUpper().Split(';').Any(prcI.name.ToUpper().Contains));
                    curCategory = cat == null ? 0 : cat.id;
                }

                if ((string.IsNullOrEmpty(prcI.name)) || (prcI.prc == 0)) continue;

                Products.Add(prcI);

                if (count == 0 || count % 200 != 0 && jrCnt != arrayTable.GetUpperBound(0)) continue;

                int start = count >= prodInTh ? count % prodInTh != 0 ? (count - count % prodInTh) : (count - prodInTh) : 0;
                int end = count % prodInTh != 0 ? (count % prodInTh) : prodInTh;

                var productsForThreadUpd = Products.GetRange(start, end).Where(x => x.ID != 0).ToList();

                var addprod = Products.GetRange(start, end).Where(x => x.ID == 0).ToList();

                if (productsForThreadUpd.Count > 0) 
                {
                    var newTh = new Thread(() => _mainClass.AddProductsUpdateProduct(productsForThreadUpd))
                        {
                            Name = company + start + " - " + (start + end) + " UPDATE"
                        };

                    newTh.Start();
                    operations.Add(newTh);
                }
                if (addprod.Count > 0)
                {
                    var newTh = new Thread(() => _mainClass.AddProductsUpdateProduct(addprod))
                        {
                            Name = company + start + " - " + (start + end) + " ADD"
                        };

                    newTh.Start();
                    operations.Add(newTh);
                }

            }
```

I split the load on the threads. In obnom stream my 200 entries.
The boot code data:

```
public void AddProductsUpdateProduct(List<Price> price)
        {
            using (var dcupdateoradd = new PriceDataContext())
            {
                if (price.Any(x => x.ID != 0))
                {
                    var upds = price.Where(x => x.ID != 0).ToList();
                    dcupdateoradd.Price.AttachAll(upds);
                    dcupdateoradd.Refresh(RefreshMode.KeepCurrentValues, upds);
                }

                dcupdateoradd.Price.InsertAllOnSubmit(price.Where(x => x.ID == 0));

                dcupdateoradd.SubmitChanges();
            }
        }
```

Do not know yet I do not like how many times the program connects to the database for the procedure, but nothing else until you come up with.

[image: Connections]

The load on the memory:

[image: load memory]

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple different ways to insert large amounts of data into SQL Database,  my favorite is SqlBulkCopy. This method requires a DataTable and will bypass Entity Framework. It allows you to stream your records to SQL Database in a very efficient manner. I use this to insert more than 70 millions rows a day into my database on Windows Azure.

You can find detailed information in the following Blogs

- [Using SqlBulkCopy to Insert Massive Amounts of Data Into Windows Azure SQL Database](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/16/using-sqlbulkcopy-to-insert-massive-amounts-of-data-into-windows-azure-sql-database/)
- [Ingesting Massive Amounts of Relational Data With Windows Azure SQL Database (70+ Million records/day)](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/ingesting-massive-amounts-of-relational-data-with-windows-azure-sql-database-70-million-recordsday/)

The other way to go about this, is to use a Stored Procedure and use the Table Valued Parameter to be able to use the INSERT INTO statement. In this scenario, you can pass a DataTable as a parameter to the Stored Procedure. Be sure that the DataTable matches 100% with the User Defined Type used by the Stored Procedure.

you can find details about using this technique in the following blog

- [Inserting Large Amounts of Data Into Windows Azure SQL Database](http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2012/10/22/inserting-large-amounts-of-data-into-windows-azure-sql-database/)

if you are looking for a way to insert more than 9000 records into the database, be sure to use the SqlBulkCopy. The Stored Procedure approach is really for small data sets.

Comment: I agree. ORM's typically don't work well with the kind of bulk action trying to be performed. SqlBulkCopy is a hidden gem.

Comment: hello! Thanks for the reply! You do not say how you can update records?

Comment: Write data to write only tables and the merge the data into Read tables. Here Is an example of merging http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/01/16/optimizing-merge-performance-in-windows-azure-sql-database/ for more information look at the following link http://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/ingesting-massive-amounts-of-relational-data-with-windows-azure-sql-database-70-million-recordsday/